# Creating a controller to manage site navigation angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` to easily manage navigation on my site. Here's my code for the navigation:

html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse" ng-controller="Navigation as AppNav">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ng-repeat="appLinks in AppNav.appLinks"><a href={{AppNav.appLinks.Page}}>{{AppNav.appLinks.Page}}</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my code for the Navigation.js controller:

```
'use strict';

(function(){
var app = angular.module('AppNav', [ ]);
app.controller('Navigation', function(){
    this.appLinks = gems;

    });
var gems = [
    {
        Page: 'Home Page',
        Link: '"#"'
    },
    {
        Page: 'About',
        Link: '"#/about"'
    },
    {
        Page: 'Contact',
        Link: '"#:'
    }
];
})();
```

I keep getting this error:

> GET http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/navigation.js 
>   angular.js:11607 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Navigation' is not a
>   function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=Navigation&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
>       at assertArg (angular.js:1580)
>       at assertArgFn (angular.js:1590)
>       at angular.js:8431
>       at angular.js:7599
>       at forEach (angular.js:331)
>       at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7586)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7078)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7081)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7081)

I'm using angular version v1.3.14. As a heads up, I'm very new to angular.js and application building so please if you can help, please let me know what I'm doing wrong along with a code sample.

Thank you all so much for your help in advance!

contents of app.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name testappApp
 * @description
 * # testappApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('testappApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Main.js:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('testappApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vutena/1/edit?html,js,output)**

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse" ng-controller="Navigation as AppNav">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ng-repeat="appLinks in AppNav.appLinks"><a ng-href={{appLinks.Link}}>{{appLinks.Page}}</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

You were referencing the Page and Link attributes wrongly. That's why no data was shown. In `ng-repeat` you have `appLinks in AppNav.appLinks` but inside the `li` tags, you were using `AppNav.appLinks.Page` which points to array. Instead you must use `appLinks.Page`

Controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

var app = angular.module('AppNav', [ ]);
app.controller('Navigation', function(){
    this.appLinks = gems;
    });



     var gems = [
    {
        Page: 'Home Page',
        Link: "/#"
    },
    {
        Page: 'About',
        Link: "/#/about"
    },
    {
        Page: 'Contact',
        Link: "/#"
    }
  ];

})();
```

Comment: Hi Mohamedrias, thanks for your input, I see you got it working but when I paste the controller and html code in my app I still see the error: `GET http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/navigation.js angular.js:11607 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Navigation' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=Navigation&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63) at assertArg (angular.js:1580) at assertArgFn (angular.js:1590) at angular.js:8431 at angular.js:7599 at forEach (angular.js:331) at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7586)`

Comment: Did you include all controllers js files?

Comment: Yes: 

`<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/navigation.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->`

Comment: Could you paste the contents of app.js and main.js

Comment: I created the app with Yeoman grunt npm... It finds the other two controllers with no problem: main.js and about.js. But not the navigation.js controller.

Comment: Edited the post with the requested app.js and main.js contents. Thanks!

Comment: what are you having in ng-app in your HTML? I don't see any reference to AppNav module as dependency in your code.

Comment: As navigation controller is a separate module AppNav, you must include it as dependency in your testapp module

Comment: Okay, what does that entail? Sorry, this is all new to me--how do I add it as a dependency? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: angular
  .module('testappApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch', 
   'AppNav'
  ])

You need to include dependencies within the [ ] in your module

Comment: Okay, I got it! Thanks so much, I thought creating a module entailed naming the module...: `var app = angular.module('enterAppName'` I thought instead of `enterAppName` you were supposed to declare the name of the module not the app name. In my case, I replaced the `var app = angular.module('AppNav', [ ]);` with `var app = angular.module('testappApp', [ ]);` Thank you so much again!

Comment: Oh, which is better? I renamed my module and it worked. Is your way the recommended way of doing this? Do I have to add dependencies on all controllers I create? Thanks!

Comment: Now you are redefining the module twice. Wherever you want to refer to the testappApp module you must use angular.module('testappApp');

Comment: It should be in the app.js not in controller. In app.js you must have angular.module('testappApp', [ ]); and in other controllers and services it must be angular.module('testappApp'); here you will get reference to that module